# Creating Trigger to auto-increment id by sequence in JDBC

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, procedure

I am writing methods through JDBC to create a table and a sequence to recall in a Trigger, I want to set up an id column which auto-increments before every insert on the table. I succeeded in building both the createTable method and the createSequence method in the DAO, but when I run the method to create the Trigger I got the java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

```
public void createTrigger() {

    PreparedStatement ps;

    StringBuilder queryTrigger = new StringBuilder();

    queryTrigger.append("CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ");
    queryTrigger.append(Tables.getInstance().getName() + "_INSERTED\n");
    queryTrigger.append("BEFORE INSERT ON " + Tabelle.getInstance().getName());
    queryTrigger.append("\nFOR EACH ROW\n");
    queryTrigger.append("BEGIN\n");
    queryTrigger.append("SELECT " + Tables.getInstance().getName() + "SEQ.NEXTVAL\n");
    queryTrigger.append("INTO :new.id\n");
    queryTrigger.append("FROM dual;\n ");
    queryTrigger.append("END;\n");
    queryTrigger.append("/\n");
    queryTrigger.append("ALTER TRIGGER " +Tabelle.getInstance().getName() + "_INSERTED ENABLE\n");
    queryTrigger.append("/\n");



    String stringQueryTrigger = queryTrigger.toString();

    Connection conn = JDBCUtility.openConnection();

    try {

        ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(stringQueryTrigger);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();


    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JDBCUtility.closeConnection(conn);}
```

---

Here instead the creation of the table does actually work even if I don't 
write the classic lines with parametrized "?" for the preparedStatement.setString(index, String)

```
public void createTable(Columns c) {    
    PreparedStatement ps;
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();



    query.append("CREATE TABLE " + Tabelle.getInstance().getName() + "(");
    query.append(Columns.getInstance().getColumnName() + " ");
    query.append(Columns.getInstance().getDataType());

    if(Columns.getInstance().isNullOrNot() == true) {
        query.append(" NOT NULL");
    }
    else {
        query.append("");           
    }
    if(Columns.getInstance().isPrimaryKeyOrNot() == true) {
        query.append(" PRIMARY KEY)");
    }
    else {
        query.append(")");
    }
    String queryToString = query.toString();



    Connection conn = JDBCUtility.openConnection();



    try {
        ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(queryToString);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();


    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JDBCUtility.closeConnection(conn);
}
```

//EDIT

turns out that is enough to substitute the PreparedStatement with a simple Statement, to get rid of the indexes mechanism and get the DB to accept the query

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: You need to execute **one** statement per execute. Currently you have two: a create and an alter trigger. You need to execute those individually. In any case, simplify your code so the executed query is entirely hardcoded, that makes it easier for us to see what other problems it may have.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 10g

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'll take the hint about hardcoding

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an auto-increment sequnce in oracle that can be used for all ids and just add the string id.NextVal to the string query

What I mean is:

Rem in oracle create sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ID

 START BY 1

 INCREMENT 1
```

// in java to execute query

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(ID.NEXTVAL);" ;
```

//rest of code

Comment: works for me, thank you, but I wanted to create a new sequence for each of the new created tables. With this query instead you call a nextval object which serves for all the tables

Comment: Why do you want seprete sequences? They don't share the same increment? If they do you can recycle the sequence for all

Comment: Exactly, they don't share the same increment. I have to create this DB for a presentation, so the more the seriality of the ID for each table is visible, the better. In a real DB this effort would be negligible, considering the amount of rows to identify. Thank you, anyway